# Streaming audio with media player

Tags: java, android, service, android-mediaplayer

I have been working on an audio stream app but I need clarity on a variety of issues. First of all, I am playing the audio file with a bound service and I have a `play-pause` button` that toggles player on and off.
These are the issues i have with my code:

1. Media player gets instantiated each time I press play button but that is not what because I also need to pause playback when needed.
2. Playback is very slow. It takes a lot of time for the `mediaplayer` to prepare and stream.
3. Sometimes media player gets initialized twice if the user vigorously toggles the `playpause` button.

Here the code:

**Music Player Activity**

```
btn_play_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!playPause) {
                    btn_play_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_button);
                    if (initialStage) {
                        musicService.play();
                        Toast.makeText(MusicPlayerActivity.this, "Playing started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    playPause = true;
                } else {
                    btn_play_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button);
                    Toast.makeText(MusicPlayerActivity.this, "Playing paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    playPause = false;
                    musicService.pause();
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

**Music Service**

```
 public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{
        private final IBinder mBinder = new MusicService.AudioBinder();
        private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        private AudioManager audioManager;
        private AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener audioFocusChangeListener;
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            return false;

        }
      @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(stream_source);
            mp.prepareAsync();
           mp.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        @Override
        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            mediaPlayer =  mp;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer = mp;
        }


        public class AudioBinder extends Binder {
            public MusicService getService() {
                //Return this instance of RadioBinder so clients can call public methods
                return MusicService.this;
            }
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return mBinder;
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
                switch (intent.getAction()) {
                    case Constants.ACTION_STOP_AUDIO_SERVICE:
                        hideNotification();
                        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        i.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        i.putExtra("close_activity",true);
                        this.startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case Constants.ACTION_STREAM_PLAY_PAUSE:
                        if (isPlaying()) {
                            pause();
                            showNotification();
                            stopForeground(false); // stop making it a foreground service but leave the notification there
                        } else {
                            play();
                            showNotification();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            return START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            setUpAudioManager();
  mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        }


        public void play() {     
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
            showNotification();
        }

        public void pause() {
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(audioFocusChangeListener);
            }
            showNotification();
        }


        public boolean isPlaying() {
            return mediaPlayer != null && (mediaPlayer.isPlaying());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null){
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
            return super.stopService(name);
        }
        public void hideNotification() {
            stopForeground(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            if(mediaPlayer!= null){
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
        }
        public void releaseTrack(){
            if(mediaPlayer!= null){
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: in your play() method you creating media player object every time. its not needed. just create once when service get started. put only play logic there. you are also not need aysnck task , because player is playing in service which runs in background

Comment: Where is the right place to initialize the media player?  onCreate?

Comment: yes in oncreate()

Comment: The issue is when I initialize my media player in onCreate, I get an illegalStateExceptionError when trying to play the media

Comment: Why is that happening ?

Comment: may be you have not set proper uri in media player

Comment: please review my edited code and help me